# How to solve: org.json.JSONException: Value GVL7TY of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to make a post request and get a string that my server generates as a response. I get this error: `D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value GVL7TY of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`. the `GVL7TY` value is the generated code from the server. I'm new to android and I don't know how to fix it. appreciate your help!

```
private void sendRequest(final String email, final String name,String url,RequestQueue queue) {
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            request.put("TeacherEmail", email);
            request.put("ClassName", name);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, request,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject responseObj) {

                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", responseObj.toString());
                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {

    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
   }
```

Comment: Hi! & welcome to StackOverflow., make a `StringRequest` instead of a `JsonObjectRequest`. I believe you use `Volley`.

Answer (score 0):

The response returned from your server is not valid json. Try debuging the raw response.